# Why is the submodule of K[x,y] generated by x and y not a free module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

If $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, and we consider the module $\mathbb{K}[x,y]$ over itself, I've seen others give the example that the ideal generated by $\langle x, y \rangle$ is not a free module to demonstrate that a submodule of a free module need not be free. However, I don't understand why.

From the definition of a free module, a module is free if it has a linearly independent basis. Since $x,y$ have no relations between them, they seem to form a linearly independent $\mathbb{K}[x,y]-$basis for the ideal. So what am I missing here? Why is this submodule not free?

Similarly, I've seen the example that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is a free module over itself but apparently $2\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not free for some reason. Again, this modules is generated by $\langle 2\rangle$ so by definition it has to be free, right?  I'm confused.

Any explanation would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: But $x$ and $y$ are dependent over $\mathbb{K}[x,y]$. We have $xy-yx=0$.

Comment: The question has been well answered by the comment above and answers below, but I just want to point out that there's nothing special about this particular example. A (nonzero) ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ is free if and only if it is principal and generated by a non-zero-divisor. One direction is clear; for the other, note that for any distinct $a, b \in I$, $ab - ba = 0$ is a nontrival $R$-linear relation between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: More generally, no non-principal ideal of a commutative ring (generated by two or more elements) is a free module, for essentially the same reason. Note that commutativity is needed, as the nontrivial relation between any two generators states exactly that they commute. So, this would fail for the left (or right) ideal generated by $x$ and $y$ in the ring generated by $K$ and two _noncommuting_ variables $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3):

They are not independent over $\mathbb{K}[x,y]$, which is the ring in question: using boldface for the module elements, you have $y\mathbf{x} -x\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{0}$, even though neither $x$ nor $y$ are zero. It is not an independent set. So it is not true that "there are no relations between them."

They *do* span a free $\mathbb{K}$-module, but that isn't what you are considering.

The subgroup $\langle2\rangle$ of the integers modulo $6$ is not free since $3\mathbf{2}=\mathbf{0}$, even though the scalar $3$ is not zero. It is not an independent set. You can also verify it does not satisfy the universal property of free modules: you cannot extend the map $\{2\}\to \mathbb{Z}_6$ that sends $2$ to $1$ to a $\mathbb{Z}_6$-module homomorphism $\langle 2\rangle\to \mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I feel kind of dumb now as this seems super obvious.

Answer (score 3):

$2\Bbb Z_6$ is generated by $2$ but it's not *freely* generated by $2$. It's not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6[X]$ for some set $X$, you can see that just by checking the cardinality. Since $3\cdot2=0$ and $3\neq0$, there is a problem... free modules must in particular be torsion free. In general for a ring $R$, $(\alpha)$ is a free (left/right) $R$-module iff. $\alpha$ is not a (left/right) zero divisor.

With $R=\Bbb K[x,y]$ and $J=(x,y)\subset R$; as a $\Bbb K$-module, $J$ is certainly free, but as an $R$-module it is not. Yes, $x,y$ generate but the generation isn't itself free; for example there is a nontrivial linear dependence $y\cdot x-x\cdot y=0$, which couldn't occur if $x,y$ were *free* generators (this in itself is not sufficient to conclude $J$ isn’t a free $R$-module, just that it is not free in the obvious ways; however, you can combine this observation with the fact ideals of a domain are free iff. they are principal to make a conclusion).

Comment: I like how you and Arturo had nearly identical answers, addressing OP's questions in opposite order.

Comment: @CameronWilliams posted at nearly identical times as well.

Comment: Oh, I see. And so $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is free over $\mathbb{Z}_6$ since there's no element that annihilates 1 in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. This feels sort of obvious now, thank you haha.